# MYSQL error #1072 - Key column 'id ' doesn't exist in table in XAMPP, phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a new table using the mysql GUI in phpmyadmin. This is the error I am getting #1072 - *Key column 'id ' doesn't exist in table*

```
CREATE TABLE `loginsys`.`groups`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `permission` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id `)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: You have a spurious space in (`id `) so the error is true.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the extra space in when you're defining  **`PRIMARY KEY(`id `)`**

This should be your query :-

```
CREATE TABLE `loginsys`.`groups`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `permission` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

simply run the query without "`"

CREATE TABLE loginsys.groups(
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            permission TEXT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(id))